# Box2d error C:\filepath\box2D.lib is not a valid Win32 app

Tags: c++, box2d

I was trying to run the hello world project that comes with the Box2D download on VS 2015. Everything build fine but I get an error C:\filepath\Box2D.lib not a valid win32 application. I looked where the file was supposed to be and it wasn't there. I am confused what is going on, and am wondering if anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I should make it clearer that Box2D wasn't installed with VS 2015, I installed Box2D and tried to run it on VS 2015

Comment: Downloaded from where exactly? Sounds like you downloaded the source code. In which case, you need to compile it to generate the Box2D library. Not sure there are pre-compiled binaries for Box2D although it might be worth a quick search.

Comment: I downloaded it from https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D, I've looked quickly it doesn't seem there is a way to get a precompiled version of box2d

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile it i.e. build the Box2D library.

To do that, install [Cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) via the Windows Installer (version 2.6 or newer is fine).

When you open the Cmake tool, set the "Where is the source code" option to wherever the Box2D source is on your computer. Set "where to build the binaries" to a new folder either inside or outside of your Box2D source folder.

Options will be visible in the Cmake UI, change them if you wish but make sure "Build static libraries" is checked.

Click "Configure". Should there be any configuration issues they will be visible in the text area at the bottom of the UI. If no issues, click "Generate", select your compiler and continue.

Assuming no issues displayed in the text area at the bottom of the UI, in the "Where to build the binaries" folder you specified earlier, open the VS solution file and then build and compile the solution. Voila, you have Box2D libraries.

Comment: When I extracted box2d there is a filepath "build/vs2015" with vc projects, one of which is helloworld.cpp. This application is meant to show new users how to run and build box2d files. So I don't think compiling it is the problem.

Comment: Did the Box2D project within the solution build without errors? Right click on it and build separate to the HelloWorld example in case project build order isn't correct. The Box2D.lib should appear in `$(OutDir)` which is the Output Directory. The Project Properties will show you the exact location for that.